# can you safely ignore the variable arguments?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

Let's say I have a function like :

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void message (const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, argptr);
    va_end(argptr);
}
```

I would like to declare in another context an empty function message, so that I provide a source-level library on an embedded platform without printf without ifdefs

I know va_start must be cleaned by va_end, but can I safely and assume the compiler will cleanup the stack if I don't use those va_ functions at all ?

would

```
void message (const char *fmt, ...) {
}
```

work ?

Comment: I assume you reference the sentence "if I don't use them at all ". In that case this is the whole va_* functions

Comment: Can you just edit the question to be understandable in a single pass? (I for one thought you were referring to "all the arguments"; anyway, readers shouldn't have to guess what you mean in order to be able to help you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can ignore any arguments you want.
To inform the compiler that's really what you wanted to do, don't give them names though.

Be aware that, unless your compiler can inline the call, your library eschewing the preprocessor and instead using empty functions will be less efficient.

To mitigate that, consider defining your empty function as an inline function in the header file.

Also, for the first one, look into defining `message` as just an alias for `printf`, as that's effectively what it looks like.

Comment: ok why not use an inline empty func. concerning the aliasing this will be interesting, however the printf function does not need to be very optimized- and might differ to specify stderr.

Comment: `printf(fmt, ...)` always has the same effect as `fprintf(stdout, fmt, ...)`. It might produce shorter code though... Also, I think I mentioned using an `inline` function, to get around the ODR.

Comment: yes, but in fact I'd like to have the caller source + header source be the same and lib source (source only compatibility). having an inline depending on stdio is not possible here. anyway, the price is very small since those will not be very often used functions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's certainly valid to ignore the variable arguments.

It's also just as valid to loop through the variable arguments multiple times.